# ZipArchive creates invalid ZIP file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to create a new ZIP package from code with one entry and save the ZIP package to a file. I am trying to achive this with the **System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive** class. I am creating the ZIP package with the following code:

```
using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("test.txt");
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(
                "Etiam eros nunc, hendrerit nec malesuada vitae, pretium at ligula.");
        }
```

Then I save the ZIP to a file either in WinRT:

```
        var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        zipStream.Position = 0;
        using (Stream s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            zipStream.CopyTo(s);
        }
```

Or in normal .NET 4.5:

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            zipStream.Position = 0;
            zipStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
```

However, I can't open the produced files neither in Windows Explorer, WinRAR, etc. (I checked that the size of the produced file matches the Length of the zipStream, so the stream itself was saved to the file correctly.)
Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with the ZipArchive class?

Comment: Here's a good example if you are adding binary data instead of strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927574/create-zip-file-in-memory-from-bytes-text-with-arbitrary-encoding

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I found the—in hindsight, obvious—error in my code. The ZipArchive has to be **disposed** to make it write its content to its underlying stream. So I had to save the stream to a file after the end of the using block of the ZipArchive.
And it was important to set the **leaveOpen** argument of its constructor to true, to make it not close the underlying stream. So here is the complete working solution:

```
using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("test.txt");
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(
                "Etiam eros nunc, hendrerit nec malesuada vitae, pretium at ligula.");
        }
    }

    var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        "test.zip",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    zipStream.Position = 0;
    using (Stream s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        zipStream.CopyTo(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error, "The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context". How can I rectify this?

Comment: Michael, this is a build error, right? Are you developing a Windows Store app, or a normal .NET app? In a normal .NET app you should use the `FileStream` class, and not the storage classes in the `Windows.Storage` namespace. You can see an example in the question.

Comment: Thanks @MarkVincze that was not entirely obvious at all to me. Saved me tearing my hair out.

Comment: I would argue it wasn't obvious at all! It has no flush or close indicating that it does this. Relying on disposal to implement functionality is disgusting design. But thanks for the post, saved my bacon.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Create file "archive.zip" in current directory use it as destination for ZIP archive
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(File.OpenWrite("archive.zip"), 
ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    // Create entry inside ZIP archive with name "test.txt"
    using (var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.txt").Open())
    {
        // Copy content from current directory file "test.txt" into created ZIP entry 
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("test.txt"))
        {
            file.CopyTo(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

In result you will get archive "archive.zip" with single entry file "test.txt".
You need this cascade of `using` to avoid any interaction with already disposed resources.

Comment: Please add an explanation for your code, and what it does to solve the question.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell done. Probably code above don't answer question directly but show how to ZIP some file using ZipArchive

Answer (score 4):

On all of your Stream Object you must rewind the streams from the beggining in order from them to be read correctly by other applications using the .Seek method.

Example:

```
zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: This did not help. This is why I set the Position property to 0, I guess that achieves the same effect.

Comment: the zip library has to have its own SaveAs method, try looking into that, also on the project peage there are various documentation with different save scenarios.

Comment: Umm, the ZipArchive class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) has no SaveAs method. What do you mean by "project page"?

Comment: sorry, i thought it was a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Freeman this did the trick in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In My case the Issue was that I was not disposing **"zipArchive"** when the zip file Task Completes. Even though I was flushing and closing all the streams.

So, Either use ***using*** as suggested in answers above

```
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(File.OpenWrite("archive.zip"), 
ZipArchiveMode.Create))
```

Or Dispose the variable at the end of the Task...

```
zipArchive.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same idea, only in reverse order, using the file stream like source. I did the form below and the file was opened normally:

```
string fileFormat = ".zip"; // any format
string filename = "teste" + fileformat;

StorageFile zipFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (Stream zipStream = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()){

   using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create)){
        //Include your content here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete code looks like this:

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.zip",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (Stream zipStream = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("test.txt");
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Etiam eros nunc, hendrerit nec malesuada vitae, pretium at ligula.");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware if using instructions without curly brackets are used (C# >8.0):

```
static byte[] CompressAsZip(string fileName, Stream fileStram)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false);
    using var entryStream = archive.CreateEntry(fileName).Open();

    fileStram.CopyTo(entryStream);

    archive.Dispose(); //<- Necessary to close the archive correctly
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Using the using statemant with curly brackets, archive.Dispose will be implicitly invoked at the end of scope.
Also, since you are using C# >8.0, I recommend an asynchronous implementation of this type, capable of archiving multiple files and being cancelled:

```
static async Task<byte[]> CompressAsZipAsync(
    IAsyncEnumerable<(string FileName, Stream FileStream)> files,
    bool disposeStreamsAfterCompression = false,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
    {
        await foreach (var (FileName, FileStream) in files.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
        {
            using var entryStream = archive.CreateEntry(FileName).Open();
            await FileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream, cancellationToken);

            if (disposeStreamsAfterCompression)
                await FileStream.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```