# Access denied deleting zip file with zip archive being read

Tags: c#, .net-core, zip, access-denied

**disclaimer** This question isn't about the appliction of `Dispose()`. It's not about files being inaccessible. I'm about closing the archive in the proper way **without** relying on disposing the object.

The following works.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, path, true);
File.Delete(file);
```

This fails with exception: *The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp...\file.zip' because it is being used by another process*.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, path, true);
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file);
File.Delete(file);
```

I've resolved it by disposing the object.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, path, true);
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file);
archive.Dispose();
File.Delete(file);
```

I am worried that disposing the object is not the correct approach. Somehow I feel there should be a way to close the file before deletion. There is [no such method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-7.0#methods), however. I googled it but the results I got were about [memory streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737800/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-ziparchive-with-memory-streams), general [access being denied](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1001281/delete-directory-access-denied-csharp), [manual setting of the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603466/21440451).

Comment: `ZipArchive` is an `IDisposable`, so it should go in a `using` which will call `Dispose` for you automatically. `using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file)) { // do stuff }`

Comment: Disposing is the correct thing to do. Closing an object generally just disposes it anyway. Sometimes it does something extra but often it doesn't. For instance, the `MemoryStream` class you mention inherits its `Close` method from the `Stream` class and, if you read the documentation for that method, it tells you that you can simply dispose the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZipFile` and `ZipArchive` implement `IDisposable`, which means that it'll invoke a call to `Dispose()` automagically at the end of the scope. Try `using` block as below.

```
void SomeMethod(string file)
{
  using ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file);
  ...
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception) { throw;` what for? If yo are just going to rethrow why catch?

Comment: @Charlieface It's not needed. A bit sloppy copy-over-syntax. I rewrote for him.