# How to create ZipArchive from files in memory in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Is it somehow possible to create a ZipArchive from the file(s) in memory (and not actually on the disk).

**Following is the use case:** 
Multiple files are received in an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` variable. I want to zip all these files together using `ZipArchive`. The problem is that `ZipArchive` only allows `CreateEntryFromFile`, which expects a path to the file, where as I just have the files in memory.

**Question:** 
Is there a way to use a 'stream' to create the 'entry' in `ZipArchive`, so that I can directly put in the file's contents in the zip?

I don't want to first save the files, create the zip (from the saved files' paths) and then delete the individual files.

Here, `attachmentFiles` is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var attachment in attachmentFiles)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(attachment.FileName), Path.GetFileName(attachment.FileName),
                                CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347775/ziparchive-creates-invalid-zip-file/12350106#12350106 ?

Comment: Why not create a temporary file and then release when the archive has completed?

Comment: I want to avoid creating a temp file and delete it afterwards, if possible. That's what I wrote in the question, but if no other way, then I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, using the [ZipArchive.CreateEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) method, as @AngeloReis pointed out in the comments, and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350106/2573395) for a slightly different problem.

Your code would then look like this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var attachment in attachmentFiles)
        {
            var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.FileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                attachment.InputStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  I used it to create a zip file of a bunch of PDFs I had stored as byte[]'s in the database.  No need to get the file system involved at all.  The user clicks a button and the .zip file is downloaded through their web browser.  (BTW, on the inner-most "using" block I instead used entryStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);

Comment: What is attachmentFiles?

Comment: I had to add `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` at the end before I could use it.

Answer (score 1):

First off thanks @Alex for the perfect answer.
Also for the scenario you need to read from file systems :

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var file in filesAddress)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

with the help of `System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions`