# Using SQL Server to Zip Files

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that stores users `FileData` as such Data Type: `varbinary(MAX) FILESTREAM null`

In my web application, the user selects multiple file Ids and eventually wants a zip file of those selected `FileId`s

Currently my solution is to bring the `FileData` into C# and call some C# function/library that zips the file and returns that to the user. The problem with this is that the user could potentially select a ton of files causing a lot of temporary data to exist in C#.

Is there a way that I can zip these files in SQL Server and then return the zipped result to C# without having to bring the selected `FileData`s into C# memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do this through a stored procedure, which would write the files and zip, but you would be writing SQL which writes files to disk and executes windows system commands. You can read up on [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I would advise against this personally

You are still going to have a large zip file blob coming back to your server in that model. Couldn't your users still overload your system? You would get around this using streaming which could be done with your zipping.

Are you using the most recent [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It provides streaming access both in and out if used properly. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896023/703644) for an example writing without bumping into memory Basically you will write your code to use an output stream so that data doesnt build up in memory [`...new ZipArchive(myOutPutStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true or false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)